# Visual studio will not undo my git changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, version-control

For some reason, my VS will not remove the files from changes view after "undo changes" :

[image]

The actual changes are gone when I view a diff, but I want the files not to show. I would like to know a permanent solution to this. I already know I can do a stash or similar outside of VS to hide the files from showing.

## EDIT:

I have found a work-around. When I undo, then with the remaining files select stage, they disappear!

Comment: glad to hear you found the workaround, you can add a reply to share your workaround and mark it as the answer.

Comment: having the same issue. for me it worked to "stage" the file that wasn't seemed to be undone. It just disappeared when staging.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your description (undo does not change file list, staging forces an update), this sounds like the following issue related to Visual Studio 2015 and 2017:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/shGitsh---shUndosh-changes-doe/681074?space=8&q=git+undo+2015

According to Microsoft, Visual Studio 2019 is also affected. The problem is now being tracked in this issue:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Undo-changes-with-new-git-experience-pre/1170228

The root cause seems to be related to line endings:

Microsoft:

> So our suspicion is that maybe `dotnet format` rewrote the line endings (and only the line-endings), so now `git status` reports that there are changed files. However, if you try to actually checkout-index, git will not actually mutate anything. However, git status believes there are changes, because the stat-block is leading it to believe there has been a change (since there has been a change).
> One way to verify this is to, from the command line, or visual studio.
> Stage everything (git add *) (you can do this from visual studio by right click > stage)
> git status (or, if in Visual Studio, it will refresh status automatically)
> If the files disappear from view, then there's a line-ending issue, and git has suddenly realized that they're actually the same file.

Reporter:

> Yes! Staging everything made all of the files disappear :-)

Microsoft:

> Cool! So here’s what we know!
> For EOL-only changes, SHA changes don’t change. Git apparently stores these internally as LF-only
> Neither checkout nor checkout-index will overwrite the file on disk
> ​Basically, since git is our source of truth here, we get misleading information. However, I think git maybe made the right decision here in regards to performance. That being said, this is super confusing from a UX perspective, so we’ll be evaluating this.
> We’re evaluating how to improve this UX.

The issue is still open but it seems that the root caused was identified. For now, there's only the workaround.